# Having trouble with creating a Read more / Read less function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On the page where I'm trying to implement this, I have several blog posts that are shortened to show a limited amount. The **read more** function expands the post on the same page with every other blog post, but my problem is that clicking this function will activate ALL of the read more / read fewer functions on the page, where I only want each individual post to expand/collapse.

```html
<div id="blog-post">
  <div class="blog-link">
    <div class="img-wrapper ">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="txt-wrapper">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<span id="read-more">[ Read More ]</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <div class="txt-wrapper">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum reiciendis dolor quae ex voluptatibus neque
        excepturi esse, provident impedit maxime odio iure, suscipit quisquam accusamus error iusto expedita ipsam fuga.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, aut.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper-large ">
      <img src="img/ikigai.jpeg" class="img-large" id="img-large" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $("#read-more").click(function () {
    $(".hidden").toggleClass("show");
    if ($(this).text() == '[ Read More ]') {
      $(this).text('[ Read Less ]');
    } else {
      $(this).text('[ Read More ]');
    }
  });
  $("#img-large").click(function () {
    $("#img-large").toggleClass("img-larger");
  });
</script>
```

I feel like the solution might be obvious so I'm sorry if it is, I just can't quite figure this out.

Comment: I could just change the #read-more id for each post to something like #read-more-1, #read-more-2, #read-more-3.. etc

Answer (score 0):

no need to make 2 section for read more / read less (if no needed for specific thing)

hope it helps you.

```js
function moreless() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("button1");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {display: none;}
```

```html
 <div id="blog-post">
            <div class="blog-link">
                <div class="img-wrapper ">
                    <img src="img/logo.png"  alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="txt-wrapper">
<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
<button onclick="moreless()" id="button1">Read more</button>
                
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="img-wrapper-large "> 
                    <img src="img/ikigai.jpeg"  class="img-large" id="img-large" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the hidden element that is next to the "read more" button by selecting the next hidden element of the closest `blog-link`. To toggle the class `img-larger` just for the clicked image instead of all images with this class change `$("#img-large").toggleClass("img-larger")` to `$(this).toggleClass("img-larger");`

```js
 $("#read-more").click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".blog-link").next(".hidden").toggleClass("show");
   if ($(this).text() == '[ Read More ]') {
     $(this).text('[ Read Less ]');
   } else {
     $(this).text('[ Read More ]');
   }
 });
 $("#img-large").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("img-larger");
 });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="blog-post">
   <div class="blog-link">
     <div class="img-wrapper ">
       <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="txt-wrapper">
       <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<span id="read-more">[ Read More ]</span></p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden">
     <div class="txt-wrapper">
       <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
       <ul>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
       </ul>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum reiciendis dolor quae ex voluptatibus neque excepturi esse, provident impedit maxime odio iure, suscipit quisquam accusamus error iusto expedita ipsam fuga.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, aut.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="img-wrapper-large ">
       <img src="img/ikigai.jpeg" class="img-large" id="img-large" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## id must be unique

If you want to identify possibly more than a single element, then do not use the `class` attribute to do so, use the `id` attribute instead, because `id` is unique and your read more link will not be unique.

## How to find the correct hidden

As you have already seen, `.hidden` is not very specific as a selector. You could identify it via `$(this).closest(".hidden")`, but that is not very safe, unless your post containers are structurally very far. You can navigate towards it using `parent()`, like

```
<div id="blog-post">
  <div class="blog-link">
    <div class="img-wrapper ">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="txt-wrapper">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<span class="read-more">[ Read More ]</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <div class="txt-wrapper">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum reiciendis dolor quae ex voluptatibus neque
        excepturi esse, provident impedit maxime odio iure, suscipit quisquam accusamus error iusto expedita ipsam fuga.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, aut.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper-large ">
      <img src="img/ikigai.jpeg" class="img-large" id="img-large" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(".read-more").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".hidden").toggleClass("show");
    if ($(this).text() == '[ Read More ]') {
      $(this).text('[ Read Less ]');
    } else {
      $(this).text('[ Read More ]');
    }
  });
  $("#img-large").click(function () {
    $("#img-large").toggleClass("img-larger");
  });
```

and this should work, unless I have missed the correct number of parent() calls.

But this is not very elegant, because you might change your structure every now and then. Apply this solution now, enjoy your success for a few minutes and then read the next section.

## Structurally stable solution

This is the line we do not like:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".hidden").toggleClass("show");
```

In order to avoid such structural assumptions, induce more information into your structure. Let's change `id="blog-post"` (see the explanation earlier) to `class="blog-post"` (note, that if you have multiple tags with the same ids, the id selector will not work, there is a solution for that as well, but it's better not to "solve" it, instead, let's use classes instead of ids whenever the tags to have that value are not unique)

Now, somewhere in your code you have a cycle which generates your blog-post tags. Change that code and add a counter, which starts from 0 and is incremented upon each iteration, so it will be 0 at the first iteration, 1 at the second, 2 at the third and so on.

If you have that counter, then you can induce a `data-count` into the reade-more, like this:

```
<span class="read-more" data-count="5">[ Read More ]</span>
```

Note, that this must be different for each read-more. Now, let's change the line we are not satisfied with to:

```
$(`.hidden:eq(${$(this).data("count")})`).toggleClass("show");
```

Note, that none of the code above was tested, so there might be typos. If you have trouble using this, then please create a JSFiddle.